# Find first Tuesday of Month

Tags: r, date

I am trying to write a function which takes a vector of dates as an input and returns a vector of dates -- where the output is the date of the first Tuesday of the month which matches the input date.

So `2012-11-19` --> `2012-11-06`, etc.

I have had some success with a single date, but have not been able to generalise to the vector case. Could someone please help?

This is what I have so far:

```
firstTuesday <- function(tt){
  ct <- as.POSIXct(tt)
  lt <- as.POSIXlt(tt)
  firstOf <- as.POSIXlt(ct - 60*60*24* (lt$mday - 1))
  if (firstOf$wday > 2) 
  {
    adjDays <- (9 - firstOf$wday)
    firstTues <- as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(firstOf) + 60*60*24*adjDays)
  }
  else {
    adjDays  <- (2 - firstOf$wday)
    firstTues <- as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(firstOf) + 60*60*24*adjDays)
  }
  return(firstTues)
}
```

Which works for a single date: `firstTuesday(Sys.Date())` but yielded junk for vectors of dates (due to issues with `if` not being a vectorised control operator, i think).

---

I got around my limited understanding by using indexing.  The following code seems to do the trick.

```
firstTuesday <- function(tt){
  ct <- as.POSIXct(tt)
  lt <- as.POSIXlt(tt)
  firstOf <- as.POSIXlt(ct - 60*60*24* (lt$mday - 1))
  firstTue <- as.POSIXct(firstOf)
  idx <- firstOf$wday > 2
  firstTue[idx]  <- as.POSIXct(firstOf[idx]) + 60*60*24*(9 - firstOf$wday[idx])
  firstTue[!idx]  <- as.POSIXct(firstOf[!idx]) + 60*60*24*(2 - firstOf$wday[!idx])
  return(firstTue)
}
```

Comment: if you're working with times and dates, I strongly recommend the lubridate package.

Comment: thanks -- perhaps i will. i am reluctant to add new package dependencies, but perhaps it's worth the costs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses lubridate and makes the logic a little simpler. Given a vector of dates the second function will return a vector of characters, similar to your input. You can change things around to suit your needs.

```
library(lubridate)

getTuesday = function(x) {
    date = ymd(x)
    first = floor_date(date,"month")
    dow = sapply(seq(0,6),function(x) wday(first+days(x)))
    firstTuesday = first + days(which(dow==3)-1)
    return(firstTuesday)
}

getMultipleTuesdays = function(y) {
    tmp = lapply(y, getTuesday)
    tmp = lapply(tmp, as.character)
    return(unlist(tmp))
}
```

*Edit*

Sample input/output

```
getMultipleTuesdays(c("2012-11-19","2012-11-19","2011-01-15"))
[1] "2012-11-06" "2012-11-06" "2011-01-04"
```

Comment: Also, changing 3 in which(dow==3) to 1-7 will allow you to pick out any day of the week, Sunday is day 1.

Comment: +1 / accepted. thanks. your example indeed solved the problem, and was the inspiration for my own (in base) solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a simple solution using base functions:

```
firstDayOfMonth <- function(dates, day="Mon", abbreviate=TRUE) {
  # first 7 days of month
  s <- lapply(as.Date(format(dates,"%Y-%m-01")), seq, by="day", length.out=7)
  # first day of month
  d <- lapply(s, function(d) d[weekdays(d,abbreviate)==day])
  # unlist converts to atomic, so use do.call(c,...) instead
  do.call(c, d)
}
```

Well, maybe the `do.call` at the end isn't so simple... but it's a handy piece of knowledge. :)

```
R> d <- as.Date(c("2012-11-19","2012-11-19","2011-01-15"))
R> firstDayOfMonth(d, "Tuesday", FALSE)
[1] "2012-11-06" "2012-11-06" "2011-01-04"
```

Comment: Whenever I see date answers solved using string parsing I throw up a little in my mouth ;)  (But I gave you an upvote anyway)

Comment: @hadley: awww, that's very sweet. :P  It was shorter and cleaner than using `POSIXlt`.

Comment: +1 / thanks Joshua. That is indeed very helpful. i'm not going to switch the accept, as 40.7k is MUCH larger than 59.