# Get 2nd and 4th Saturday of Month

Tags: r, date

```
d = seq(as.Date("2018-01-01"),Sys.Date(),by='day')
saturdayList = d[weekdays(d)=='Saturday']
```

How to get the 2nd and 4th saturday of a month from above list of Saturday dates?

Comment: [Relevant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23354069/how-to-figure-third-friday-of-a-month-in-r), [so is this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13448588/find-first-tuesday-of-month)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can split the vector into a list and extract the 2nd and 4th element per month:

```
lapply(split(saturdayList, format(saturdayList, "%Y-%m")), `[`, c(2, 4))
# $`2018-01`
# [1] "2018-01-13" "2018-01-27"
# 
# $`2018-02`
# [1] "2018-02-10" "2018-02-24"
# 
# $`2018-03`
# [1] "2018-03-10" "2018-03-24"
# 
# $`2018-04`
# [1] "2018-04-14" "2018-04-28"
# ...
```

Without NA's:

```
lapply(split(saturdayList, format(saturdayList, "%Y-%m")), function(x)
       na.omit(x[c(2,4)]))
```

Assumptions:

- The input is ordered by date (as in the example)
- The input is a complete sequence without missing saturdays (as in the example)

Comment: Are you sure? if it's 2nd in list does that mean it's falls 2nd on the month calendar as well?

Comment: Well this assumes that your input is ordered by date, as it is in your example. And it also assumes, that your saturdayList sequence is complete over the timespan. If there are missing days (saturdays) in your input list, this approach wouldn't find them or report false

Comment: Can you make it so it returns like a list without `NA`?

Answer (score 1):

`data.table` solution

The solution is slower (on the sample data), than the 'lapply-solution' from docendo discimus. However, it is very flexible, and will alsoperform quite well on larger data-sets.

```
library(data.table)
#build a data.table out of the vector
DT <- data.table(date = d)
#group by month, select the second and 4 row where wday == 7 (i.e. Saturday)
DT[ DT[ , .I[wday(date) == 7][c(2,4)], by = .(month(date)) ]$V1 ]
```

**output**

```
# date
# 1: 2018-01-13
# 2: 2018-01-27
# 3: 2018-02-10
# 4: 2018-02-24
# 5: 2018-03-10
# 6: 2018-03-24
# 7: 2018-04-14
# 8: 2018-04-28
# 9: 2018-05-12
# 10: 2018-05-26
# 11: 2018-06-09
# 12: 2018-06-23
# 13: 2018-07-14
# 14: 2018-07-28
# 15: 2018-08-11
# 16: 2018-08-25
# 17: 2018-09-08
# 18: 2018-09-22
# 19: 2018-10-13
# 20: 2018-10-27
# 21: 2018-11-10
# 22: 2018-11-24
# 23: 2018-12-08
# 24: 2018-12-22
# date
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be much simpler just to get date, instead of `.I` and subsetting data.table yet again?

Example: `DT[wday(date) == 7, date[c(2,4)], by = .(month(date)) ]`

Comment: @Jav I guess.. output looks the same, but in the past I've had some nasty surprises with subsetting grouped DT's. That's why this is now my 'default' method... I guess it's time for me to read up on data.table again ;-)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** This calculates a vector of 2nd and 4th Saturdays directly from `d` although we could replace `d` with `saturdayList` and it would still work.

Define `nextsat`, based on `nextfri` in the [zoo quickref vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-quickref.pdf), which gives the next Saturday on or after the input date for each element of the input vector.  Then for each element of `d` find the first of the month, apply `nextsat` to give the first Saturday of the month and add 7 to get the second Saturday of each month.  Add 14 to get the 4th Saturday and sort into a single vector.  No packages are used.

```
nextsat <- function(x) 7 * ceiling(as.numeric(x-6+4) / 7) + 
  as.Date(6-4, origin = "1970-01-01")

sat2 <- unique(nextsat(as.Date(cut(d, "month")))) + 7
sort(c(sat2, sat2 + 14))
```

giving:

```
 [1] "2018-01-13" "2018-01-20" "2018-02-10" "2018-02-17" "2018-03-10"
 [6] "2018-03-17" "2018-04-14" "2018-04-21" "2018-05-12" "2018-05-19"
[11] "2018-06-09" "2018-06-16" "2018-07-14" "2018-07-21" "2018-08-11"
[16] "2018-08-18" "2018-09-08" "2018-09-15" "2018-10-13" "2018-10-20"
[21] "2018-11-10" "2018-11-17" "2018-12-08" "2018-12-15" "2019-01-12"
[26] "2019-01-19" "2019-02-09" "2019-02-16" "2019-03-09" "2019-03-16"
```

**2)** This computes a vector `satno` giving the number of each Saturday within its month and then picks off the second and fourth. This also does not use any packages.

```
satno <- ave(as.numeric(saturdayList), cut(saturdayList, "month"), FUN = seq_along)
saturdayList[satno %in% c(2, 4)]
```